# for which values of $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ is $f$ integrable?

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

For which values $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ is $f$ integrable?

$$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R} : f(x, y) = x \frac{\ln(1 + x^2
+ y^2)}{(x^2 + y^2)^\alpha} $$

if $ (x,y) \neq (0, 0) $ and $ f(0, 0) =
2015$.

I tried to solve this question by switching variables to polar coordinates but I couldn't.

Answer (score 6):

$f$ is integrable if and only if ${3\over 2}<\alpha < {5\over 2}$. Polar coordinates are actually useful. Write $(x,y)=r(\sin\theta,\cos\theta)$ and then you have
$$f(x,y)dxdy=f(r,\theta)rdrd\theta=\sin\theta r^{2-2\alpha} \log(1+r^2)drd\theta$$
$f$ is clearly continuous away from the origin so we need only check what happen near zero and "near" infinity.

In a punctured neighborhood of the origin, the dependence of $f$ on $r$ is of the order of $r^{4-2\alpha}$ (because $\log(1+r^2)/r^2\to 1$ as $r \to 0$)
so for $f$ to be integrable near the origin we need $4-2\alpha>-1$. Now, when $r\to\infty$ we need the power of $r$ to be smaller than $-1$, that is, $2-2\alpha < -1$. Combining these two inequalities for $\alpha$ gives the result as stated above.

Comment: When using polar coordinates, there's a factor $r$ that comes with the Jacobian, so instead of integrating $f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$ you should be integrating $rf(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$.

Comment: Of course you are right! I've corrected my answer

Comment: @Mercy You mis-calculated the substitution, $t=r^{-1}$, which gives $dt=-dr/r^2$ and so the result is $\int_0^1 t^{2\alpha-4}\log (1+t^{-2})dt$ which is convergent for $\alpha>3/2$.